# FreeBSD KVM port maturity

Tags: freebsd, linux-kvm

What information is available on the stability and maturity of the FreeBSD KVM port?

> Please only share in-depth articles on why it would be stable, or why it wouldn't be based on real life experiences.
>
> "I've been running it for 2 years on my closet server without any problems!" will only get this question closed / marked as off-topic.

(edit) to clarify: this is about FreeBSD being the host system, not a KVM guest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK it's long unmaintained.  The proper FreeBSD hypervisor is BHyVe, see https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/virtualization-host-bhyve.html.